# How to implement __getitem__ such that it can process the input args and then pass them into the underlying numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading, numpy-slicing

Let A be a simple python class that has one member self._mat which is a numpy array.
The constructor of A gets an integer n and creates an inner n by n zeros numpy array and saves it as the private member self._mat.

How can I implement `__getitem__` such that I can first preprocess the arguments passed to `__getitem__` (for instance map certain strings, such as serialized IDs, into zero-based integer indices), and then pass them into the inner numpy array self._mat such that it will be handled the same way as if the user of the class simply passed the processed arguments straight into the inner numpy array?

An example (bad) implementation of A looks like this:

```
class A():
     def __init__(self, n: int=3):
         self._mat = np.zeros(shape=[n, n])
     def __getitem__(self, val):
         # This implementation is wrong and doesn't pass interpretation...
         val = _process_val(val)  # How do I process this correctly such that I look at the inner elements of each index in the POSSIBLE multi-index as well?
         return self._mat[val]
```

Example usages:

```
a = A(n=4)
print(a[0], a[0, 1], a[(0, 1)], a[:, 1:2])
# Lets say that the string 'deadbeef' is cast onto the integer 0
print(a['deadbeef'], a['deadbeef', 1], a[('deadbeef', 1)], a[:, 'deadbeef':2])
```

Comment: `arg = _process_arg(arg)` assigns the function return to the loop variable `arg` - it doesn't modify `args`.

Comment: Thats besides the point.. I could also iterage over range of `len(args)` and change `args[i]`... Its more of a pseudo code to illustrate what I meant to do

Comment: `__getitem__` gets exactly *one* argument, which itself may be a tuple, not multiple arguments.

Comment: @TalAfek sorry I seem to have irritated you - please know that it was a genuine attempt to help find the problem.

Comment: @TalAfek It's not besides the point. Example code that doesn't work makes it much harder for us to debug, as we need to figure out all those small problems first before tackling *actual* issue.

Comment: Alright I understood your point. I will edit the code then, please take a look again in a moment. And don't worry, you haven't irritated me, I'm just looking for answers and I thought you didn't understand my point

Comment: BTW, If this class is only ever gonna contain only this single attribute, you most likely should use inheritance instead. This will guarantee you are not missing any behaviour of the contained object without having to explicitly define all the methods.

Comment: numpy has a `indexing_tricks` file with a number of classes with custom `getitem` methods.  It may give you ideas on how to do cute stuff yourself.A key step is being able to handle a tuple argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic idea can be solved with recursion - changing all the elements you want, while keeping same general structure of an argument.

```
import numpy as np

def process_arg(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        if arg == "deadbeef":
            return 0
    if isinstance(arg, tuple):
        return tuple(process_arg(a) for a in arg)
    else:
        return arg


class A():
    def __init__(self, n: int=3):
        self._mat = np.zeros(shape=[n, n])
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        arg = process_arg(arg)
        return self._mat.__getitem__(arg)

a = A(n=4)
print(a[0], a[0, 1], a[(0, 1)], a[:, 1:2])
print(a['deadbeef'], a['deadbeef', 1], a[('deadbeef', 1)])
```

Handling slices as in `a[:, 'deadbeef':2]` I'll leave as an exercise to you.